# Any difference in "return View()" and "return PatialView()" still in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, partial-views

So somebody asked me the question:

> When would I return View() and when would I return PartialView()?

My immdiate reaction was, *if it's a patial use `PartialView()`*. Then I realised that I have quite often returned `View()` for a partial view with no, apparent, detremental effects?! So what's the point in the `return PartialView()` call?

I found this question [What's the difference between “return View()” and “return PartialView()”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662285/whats-the-difference-between-return-view-and-return-partialview). This appears to be particular to MVC2. i.e. talks about `.aspx` and `.ascx` control extensions. Using Razor all our views are `.cshtml` whether they are partial or not.

Which got my thinking is the `PartialView()` just a hangover from MVC2 and not really relevant in MVC3+ (When using Razor anyway)? Or am I missing some crucial feature of `PartialView()`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872512/what-is-the-point-of-partial-views-in-asp-net-mvc/18873011#18873011

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**MSDN Reference:**

If you contrast the MSDN definition for [ViewResult() Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewresult%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) with the MSDN definition for [PartialViewResult() Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.partialviewresult%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

you find the only difference is that ViewResult has an extra property:

```
public string MasterName { get; set; }
```

Otherwise, both Objects inherit from [ViewResultBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewresultbase%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) and seem to inherit all other properties and methods from the base class.

Unfortunately, the implementation of the  abstract method [ExecuteResult()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewresultbase.executeresult%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) is not published, but I have no doubt it uses the `MasterName` field to find and render the Master Layer.

---

**Our shared experience:**

Just like you, I have returned partial views =using View(). I don't recommend it. But the apparent difference isn't big.

It does seem a touch wasteful to have an extra object just for MasterName, but the more important difference is probably the implementation of `ExecuteResult()`.

When you choose `View()` method and create a `ViewResult` Object rather than using PartialView() to create a PartialViewResult Object, you are being less efficient; your application is doing the extra work of checking if your `MasterName` field is assigned.

Answer (score 7):

**tl;dr:** `PartialView()` does not use a layout for the view being returned.

---

You can set a default layout file within `_ViewStart.cshtml` (located in the `Views` folder) which will then be used by all views. By doing that, you avoid having to set the `Layout` property within each view. `PartialView()` will not include that layout file or any other.

If you want to return a partial view, e.g. in a child action called using `@Html.Action(action, controller)`, use `PartialView`. If you want to return a "full" view including the layout, use `View()`.

Comment: Doesn't really answer my question. My layouts are generally declared in the View. There is no reason that I can see why I **can't** return `View` for a `@Html.Action`? Nothing breaks if I do?

Comment: @Liam You didn't say anything about `@Html.Action` in your question, so I pointed out the difference of the two methods in treating the layout files.

Comment: *Or am I missing some crucial feature of PartialView()?*, yes you are.  Views should **not** be aware of what layout they are using, otherwise they are not [re-usable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_reuse).